# Is there a name for The God Who Hears?

Tags: names-of-god

I was wondering if there is a name meaning *God Who Hears me*.

**El Roi** speaks of *The God Who Sees me*.  From Genesis 16:13 (ESV):

> <sup>**13**</sup> So she called the name of the LORD [El-Roi] who spoke to her, "You are a God of seeing," for she said, "Truly here I have seen him who looks after me."

<s>Googling *God Who Hears* turned up one site that (incorrectly?) said **Jehovah-Shammah** (usually translated *The Lord Who Is Present* or *The Lord Is There*) meant *God Who Hears me*.  Their given verse was Psalm 17:6 (ESV):</s>

> <sup><s>**6**</s></sup> I call upon you, for you will answer me, O God; incline your ear to me; hear [shama`] my words.

<s>I don't know Hebrew at all, but checking Strong's online out of curiosity, [shama`] and [shammah] seem (to me) to be unrelated words.</s>

**Does anyone know of a name that meant *God Who Hears me*?**

Comment: This quest may be better asked here: http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ or http://judaism.stackexchange.com/ as I know of no Christian denomination who uses the names of God in this way.

Comment: @TheFreemason -- It's pretty common in some circles; I've seen names of God used as worship service themes in protestant churches, and there are popular bible study guides based on studying one name of God at a time.

Comment: @Nathaniel I should have been more careful.  There are many different denominations and within those, different practices (snake handling comes to mind).  It is almost impossible to say, "these people do not exist" in regards to any topic.  With that said, I still believe the question is better placed on the two other SE's mentioned.

Comment: @Nathaniel The question is about the Hebrew language and slightly about Jewish culture, not Christianity the religion. That's why it's off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the Hebrew language and perhaps a bit about Jewish culture, not about Christianity.

Comment: @fredsbend It's my first question.  Can't you suggest how I might improve it (such as by removing the incidental Hebrew I don't even speak or read, if that's the objection), instead of closing it?  I was simply looking for a Christian perspective about whether a specific (English) name existed for God.

Comment: @PetahChristian I think as a Christ you're welcome to call upon God however you like. But you're question is about Hebrew names for God found in the Bible. I don't know how to make that on-topic here. This site is about cataloging Christian beliefs and practices. I'm sure there's a larger on-topic question about how, when, and why certain Christians call upon God, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking.

Comment: My question was if He had a name, not specifically whether He had a **Hebrew** name.  The only reason I mentioned the Hebrew was because I tried to find an answer on my own, by Googling 'God Who Hears', and there was one solitary site mentioning 'God Who Hears' that listed English/Hebrew names, but their info didn't seem correct, not that I know.  I don't know Hebrew :)  Let's not make it about Hebrew :)  It was a simple Christian question about God and/or whether there was a bible verse about this.

Comment: @fredsbend Just curious; what about "Have any Christian authors referred to God as 'The God Who Hears,' and if so, on what biblical basis?"  This would make my answer not particularly on target, but would allow an answer like "Yes, Ann Spangler includes this in her book ___ and bases it on Psalm 17:6..."

Comment: This question is being discussed in a meta post: [Asking other Christians a question about God](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4598)

Comment: Let's see what someone can come up with in meta. Your suggestion is probably fine, but doesn't sound like what the OP wants.

Comment: The question that @Nathaniel mentioned would fit, as I am simply *curious* about this.  I'm not a scholar; I'm simply fascinated by God, want to know more about Him, and would like to dwell with Him. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close: **'El Shama** is what you are looking for.  Shama means "to hear" ([Strong's](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/8085.htm)) and is found in Psalm 17:6, as you mention.  Furthermore, the name *Ishmael* is derived from these two words:

> And the angel of the Lord said to her, “Behold, you are pregnant and shall bear a son.
>   You shall call his name Ishmael, because the Lord has listened to your affliction. ([Genesis 16:11 (ESV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+16:11&version=ESV))

The ESV note specifically says, "*Ishmael* means *God hears*," and so does [Strong's Concordance](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/3458.htm).

There's also the name "Elishama," [meaning "God has heard,"](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/476.htm) which belongs to several Israelites listed in the genealogies of the OT (e.g., [Numbers 1:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+1%3A10&version=ESV) and [1 Chronicles 2:41](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Chronicles+2%3A41&version=ESV)).

The "Shammah" rendering you saw may be due to the pronunciation; Strong's gives the phonetic spelling of Shama as "shaw-mah."

Comment: Does "El Shama" appear anywhere in the Bible?

Comment: Not that I can find.  But I uncovered one more name that is transliterated even more closely than Ishmael; I've added it to my answer.

Comment: And for what it is worth, "the Lord has listened" in Gen 16:11 is translated from "Yahweh shaama."